# Procedurally Creating Tiny Imperfections using Shader or Geometry Nodes

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, 3d-printing, shader-nodes

I'm working on a project where I'm importing GCODE (that is a file that a 3d printer takes in and prints an object for you) and displaying it on Blender. This is what I have so far. Please understand that each of those slices is a Polyline Curve with bevel geometry applied. So that's 100s of Curves with 100s of points each.

[image]

You can see there are a ton of imperfections there and that is how I want it. But they are all where the plastic is missing. Sometimes a printer oozes more plastic than needed. Something like this:
[image]

This is also just a blender plugin where these small blobs are being generated using just a shader, I believe (I could be wrong). This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. It would be awesome if it could be done just in the shader because that would save me render time, else if it's possible to do it using geometry nodes.

Comment: It would be a good idea to share your blend file with us so we can take a closer look.